# how to combine a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

i have a list of dictionary as

```
[{'task_count': 2, 'task_status': 'approved', 'application_id': 252},
 {'task_count': 4, 'task_status': 'assigned', 'application_id': 252},
 {'task_count': 4, 'task_status': 'assigned_for_review', 'application_id': 252},
 {'task_count': 2, 'task_status': 'ready_for_review', 'application_id': 252},
 {'task_count': 3, 'task_status': 'assigned', 'application_id': 234},
 {'task_count': 11, 'task_status': 'assigned', 'application_id': 232},
 {'task_count': 2, 'task_status': 'cancelled', 'application_id': 232}]
```

I want to combine them based on application id

Comment: Combine how? Your question is unclear - and doesn't show any effort to solve the problem...

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the instructions for posting a question next time, as your question is a bit unclear which has been pointed out by the comments above. Do you want to summarize the __task_count__ entries based on __application_id__?

Answer (score 0):

maybe that's what you were looking for

```
list_dict = [{'task_count': 2, 'task_status': 'approved', 'application_id': 252}, {'task_count': 4, 'task_status': 'assigned', 'application_id': 252}, {'task_count': 4, 'task_status': 'assigned_for_review', 'application_id': 252}, {'task_count': 2, 'task_status': 'ready_for_review', 'application_id': 252}, {'task_count': 3, 'task_status': 'assigned', 'application_id': 234}, {'task_count': 11, 'task_status': 'assigned', 'application_id': 232}, {'task_count': 2, 'task_status': 'cancelled', 'application_id': 232}]

result = {x["application_id"]:x for x in list_dict}.values()

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
dict_values([{'task_count': 2, 'task_status': 'ready_for_review', 'application_id': 252}, {'task_count': 3, 'task_status': 'assigned', 'application_id': 234}, {'task_count': 2, 'task_status': 'cancelled', 'application_id': 232}])
```